# Failed to read SSH Private key stored at path

Tags: rundeck

I am getting this error when any user besides `admin` runs the job:

`Failed to read SSH Private key stored at path: keys/rundeck/id_rsa:` `com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.storage.StorageAuthorizationException: Unauthorized access`

Where should I be looking to solve this error?

TIA.

Comment: Check the credentials of your key file. What permissions does it have (chmod) ? the keyfile is probably owned by Admin and so other users will not be given access to it.

Comment: How do I check the permissions? From the Rundeck server that it's hosted on? or from the GUI?
Also, how to enable this key to be accessed by other users? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to grant access to key storage to your user/roles, this ACL grant access to the Rundeck Key Storage:

```yaml
description: project context.
context:
  project: ProjectEXAMPLE
for:
  resource:
    - allow: [run,read]
  job:
    - allow: [read,view,update,run]
  node:
    - allow: [read,run]
by:
  username: user
 
---

description: app context.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  project:
  - allow: read
    match:
      name: ProjectEXAMPLE
  storage:
     - allow: [read]
by:
  username: user
```

Check the app context storage section.

But if you want to limit to an specific key you will use [this](https://kcaps.medium.com/rundeck-key-storage-acl-grant-access-to-path-27da34345220) approach. e.g:

```yaml
description: project context.
context:
  project: ProjectEXAMPLE
for:
  resource:
    - allow: [run,read]
  job:
    - allow: [read,view,update,run]
  node:
    - allow: [read,run]
by:
  username: user
 
---

description: app context.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  project:
  - allow: read
    match:
      name: ProjectEXAMPLE
  storage:
    - match:
        path: 'keys/rundeck'
      allow: [read]
by:
  username: user
```

In both cases if you want to focus your ACL to a specific role change "username" by "group".

Considering that you're using the key `keys/rundeck` to access the remote node.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
  <node name="node00" description="NODE 00" tags="canada" hostname="192.168.56.20" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64" username="vagrant" ssh-key-storage-path="keys/rundeck"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Great! Remember to mark the answer as an correct answer. Have a nice one.